# Regex to parse image link in Markdown

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create regex to parse markdown links.

regex:

```
!\[[^\]]*\]\((.*)\s"(.*[^"])"?\s*\)
```

Test ([link to live demo](http://regexr.com/3g21r)):

```
foo

![](image 2.png "hello world")

bar
```

Group 1 will be `image 2.png`, and group 2 will be `hello world`.

The problem appears when I try to parse a link without title:

```
foo

![](image 2.png)

bar
```

How I should modify regex to make it work in both cases?

Comment: the first `"` in the pattern in not optional so it would never match without quoted title. Also, group1 and group2 do not match what you say they do currently.

Comment: "Also, group1 and group2 do not match what you say they do currently" -- Strange. For me, it works. As well, as in the live demo.

Comment: See http://regexr.com/3g221

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, also :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to make the second group optional since it's not always there. Also, you can achieve a little bit better readability with named groups, something like this perhaps:

```
!\[[^\]]*\]\((?<filename>.*?)(?=\"|\))(?<optionalpart>\".*\")?\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/cSbfvF/3/

Alternatively, your original regex fixed up would be:

```
!\[[^\]]*\]\((.*?)\s*("(?:.*[^"])")?\s*\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/u2DwY2/2/

Comment: @sweaver2112 Thanks for your answer. I am not able to use the first one with python3 're' module. By any chance would you know why?

Comment: hi Jim, it could be the named group syntax, shouldn't it be `(?P<name>...)` for Python?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete regexp to match both the Alt text and the image url in a markdown file with a named capture group:

```js
(?<alt>!\[[^\]]*\])\((?<filename>.*?)(?=\"|\))\)
```

Answer (score 1):

The previously accepted answer only accounts for standard images, it's possible however that images could be used as links for hyperlinks, resulting in a nested image reference, such as:

```
![alt-text](http://example.com/image.png "image title")](http://example.com/some?target)
```

A more complete regex pattern would like like this:

```
\[?(!)(?'alt'\[[^\]\[]*\[?[^\]\[]*\]?[^\]\[]*)\]\((?'url'[^\s]+?)(?:\s+(["'])(?'title'.*?)\4)?\)
```

This pattern also provides named groups for all the potential other info you might want about the image, such as "alt text" or "title".

Comment: Thank you a lot. I don't use Markdown anymore, though: I have switched to Asciidoctor.